# Angular issue with minification and multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have the following scenario that works perfectly in debug mode, but as soon as I run it in release mode the second function (details page) is never triggered - I can only assume it has to do with minification.

Perhaps my design is the problem, but with my limited knowledge of Angular I need some advise on this.

**Scenario:**

- 2 MVC pages (First a summary list, second a details page)
- 1 ng-app instance
- 1 module
- 2 controllers - 1 per page.

On the first page the angular values resolve correctly, but on the details page all I see is the *"{{ form.logEntry.Message }}"* text (only in Release mode). This renders correctly in debug mode.

In the MVC pages I initiate the controllers as follows:

- Summary page: `<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="LogEntriesController as table">`
- Details page: `<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="LogEntryController as form">`

The outline of the angular code is as follows:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var logEntryApp = angular.module('magiclogs',[]);

    logEntryApp.controller('LogEntriesController', LogEntriesController)
    LogEntriesController.$inject = ['$scope','$filter','$http','$q','$timeout'];

    logEntryApp.controller('LogEntryController', LogEntryController);
    LogEntryController.$inject = ['$scope','$filter','$http','$q'];

    function LogEntriesController($scope, $filter, $http, $q, $timeout)
    {
    ....
    };

    function LogEntryController($scope, $filter, $http, $q)
    {
    ....
    };
})();
```

The browser console points to an Unknown Provider error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n

Any insights/corrections welcomed.

Comment: Any logs in browser console dev tools?

Comment: Post updated but it is the unknown provider error (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n)